# Override the default validation that fires when a non-nullable value is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have been recently digging into validation annotations on our project and making custom ones by overriding the isvalid callback.  No big deal.  I may not be using them totally correctly yet but i'm still learning how they work.  However if i have my newly created "required" annotation on a non-nullable field (say, integer), it never fires.  It runs some other kind of validator and i can't discover what it is or how to interrupt or override it.  The purpose of this is we are styling all of our error messages to the top of every page because some pages have tabs on them.  If you try to save a record from a tabbed interface and you leave a field empty on a different tab, you won't save but won't see why either.  I would like to override the not-null check somehow that trumps everything else i'm doing, or B:  override the styling of the error message it puts out.

Comment: i could post some code samples tomorrow, but i don't see how it's broad.  Custom validation is not firing on non-nullable fields.  I want to know if i can stop it or replace it or edit it.

Answer (score 0):

`int` is a primitive data type with a default value of 0. The reason the `[Required]` attribute seems like it's not working is because the `int` actually does have a value of 0. You can make the `int` nullable by declaring it with `int?` The `[Required]` attribute should fire if a value hasn't been supplied.

Comment: that's an option and we are actually doing that.  I just was hoping there would be some way to, if not stop THAT error message, at least style it.  I thought we would be able to trap the error and replace it somehow with a custom one.